# Writing a function to filter a list of a items by a property on it's base type in c#

Tags: c#, linq, types

Lets say we have some types defined as so:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class SubClassA : BaseClass
{
    public bool SomeBoolValue { get; set; }
}

public class SubClassB : BaseClass
{
    public decimal SomeDecimalValue { get; set; }
}
```

And we construct two lists of the sub class type like this

```
List<SubClassA> subClassAList = new List<SubClassA>
{
    new SubClassA {SomeBoolValue = true, Value = 0},
    new SubClassA {SomeBoolValue = true, Value = 2},
    new SubClassA {SomeBoolValue = false, Value = 1},

};

List<SubClassB> subClassBList = new List<SubClassB>
{
    new SubClassB {SomeDecimalValue = 1.3M, Value = 2},
    new SubClassB {SomeDecimalValue = 3.5M, Value = 1},
    new SubClassB {SomeDecimalValue = 0.2M, Value = 5},
};
```

Is there a way we can implement a function that can can filter both subClassAList and subClassBList on the Value property?
I know this can be achieved through casting the results of a function like so:

```
    public static IEnumerable<BaseClass> OrderList(IEnumerable<BaseClass> list)
    {
        return list.OrderBy(x => x.Value);
    }

...
...

        orderedAList = OrderList(subClassAList)
            .Cast<SubClassA>() //Don't like requiring a cast. Unsafe.
            .ToList();
```

But then we need to cast the results to get it back into the subclass list which doesn't seem very typesafe. I know the ordering operation in itself is very simple and it probably doesn't warrant a separate function to do the action, but if you were trying to do something more complex than ordering, it would be helpful to contain the logic to a single function/class/whatever in order to do achieve it rather than copying code.

Comment: Why not just call `.OrderBy(x => x.Value)` on the list? If you call it on a `List<SubClassA>` it returns an enumerable of `SubClassA` unless you cast it to a `Base` list, right?

Comment: Because if you wanted to order the A list and the B list, you would have to write the code `OrderBy(x => x.Value)` twice. Honestly if it's just ordering it wouldn't be a big deal to do this, but I'm looking for solutions to this small problem so I can get ideas on how to extrapolate it to operations that would be more complex than ordering and require multiple steps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could accomplish this using a generic method.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderList<T>(IEnumerable<T> list) where T : BaseClass
{
return list.OrderBy(x => x.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. I just applied it to a more complex filter function that I was using and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an interface for these class like this:

```
 public interface IBaseClass
{
  int Value { get; set; }
}

ublic class BaseClass:IBaseClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class SubClassA : BaseClass,IBaseClass
{
    public bool SomeBoolValue { get; set; }
}

public class SubClassB : BaseClass,IBaseClass
{
    public decimal SomeDecimalValue { get; set; }
}
```

And now you can easily to filter both subClassAList and subClassBList on the Value property.

```
public static IEnumerable<IBaseClass> OrderList(IEnumerable<IBaseClass> list)
    {
        return list.OrderBy(x => x.Value);
    }



orderedAList = OrderList(subClassAList)
            .ToList()
```

Comment: Isn't this similar to the example I provided? The OrderList function would just yield an enumarble of IBaseClass instead of BaseClass. The result would still need to be cast back to the sub class list type in order to operate on it as a list of SubClassA or SubClassB

Comment: but it's safe casting

Comment: still having  upcasting in case you use generic method

Answer (score 0):

You  can use generic class to resolve this issue as shown below:

```
class LinqUtil<T> where T : BaseClass
{
    static void MyMain()
    {
        List<SubClassA> subClassAList = new List<SubClassA>
        {
            new SubClassA {SomeBoolValue = true, Value = 0},
            new SubClassA {SomeBoolValue = true, Value = 2},
            new SubClassA {SomeBoolValue = false, Value = 1},

        };

        List<SubClassB> subClassBList = new List<SubClassB>
        {
            new SubClassB {SomeDecimalValue = 1.3M, Value = 2},
            new SubClassB {SomeDecimalValue = 3.5M, Value = 1},
            new SubClassB {SomeDecimalValue = 0.2M, Value = 5},
        };

        IList<SubClassA> orderedAList = LinqUtil<SubClassA>.OrderList(subClassAList)
        .ToList();

        IList<SubClassB> orderedBList = LinqUtil<SubClassB>.OrderList(subClassBList)
        .ToList();

    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> OrderList(IEnumerable<T> list) 
    {
        return list.OrderBy(x => x.Value);
    }
}
```